# C++ Multiple delimiters with more than one char

Tags: c++, stdstring

In c++, I'm having trouble coding multiple delimiters with single char delimiters and string delimiters (e.g. "<=" as a delimiter as opposed to '='). The code below works with single char delimiters (I've set the delimiters as space, comma, dot, plus and equal) and separates the words in string line nicely. However, I don't know how to add string delimiters to this code.

```
std::string delimiters = " ,.+=";//I want "<=" added as a single delimiter
std::string line = "this+is,a.string=testing one";
std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
while ((pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, prev)) != std::string::npos)
{
    if (pos > prev)
    {
        cout << line.substr(prev, pos-prev) << endl;
        prev = pos + 1;
    }
}
if (prev < line.length()){
    cout << line.substr(prev, std::string::npos) << endl;
}
```

Comment: try std::string delimiters = " ,.+=\"<=\"";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inside a std::string, is it possible to find the first of a set of strings without using a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334057/inside-a-stdstring-is-it-possible-to-find-the-first-of-a-set-of-strings-witho)

Comment: I tried adding \"<=\" to delimiters and the loop hangs once it finds "<=". I need to somehow implement this with the while loop as it is part of my program.

Comment: That simply isn't how `find_first_of` works. If you want to use `find_first_of` then *you* need to determine whether `<` is followed by `=` *once you find `<` first*. If it isn't, then it is simply part of the current lexeme and the hunt goes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it by erasing the delimiters you find from the line_copy string, having a special if statement for the special delimiter. Full [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d064f2fc4adaa3b):

```
auto pos = find_first_of(begin(line_copy), end(line_copy), begin(delimiters), 
                         end(delimiters));

while (pos != line_copy.end()) {
    if (pos != line_copy.end()) {
        if (*pos == '<' && *(pos + 1) == '=') {
            cout << "delimiter: \'";
            cout << string(pos, pos + 2) << "\'" << endl;

            // remove the delimiters from copy string
            line_copy.erase(pos, pos + 2);
        }
        else {
            cout << "delimiter: \'" << *pos << "\'" << endl;

            // remove the delimiters from copy string
            line_copy.erase(pos, pos + 1);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    pos = find_first_of(begin(line_copy), end(line_copy), begin(delimiters), 
                        end(delimiters));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the line

```
rev = pos + 1
```

in the following way:

```
if (pos > prev)
{
    cout << line.substr(prev, pos-prev) << endl;
    prev = line.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos))
}
```

So once you hit a delimiter then you move to the fiurst char not being a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Do a two character search one by one.
Search for "<" first and if found search for an immediate "=" if found, do substr otherwise continue searching.